# Azure's Ubuntu 12.0.4 fails to install PHP5

Tags: php, ubuntu, azure, apt-get

Similar to this article from Azure themselves:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/install-lamp-stack/

I am trying to install PHP5 on Ubuntu 12.0.4 virtual machine. However, it fails installing the ssl-cert.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.28) ...
Could not create certificate. Openssl output was:
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
............................+++
...................................................................................................................+++
writing new private key to '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
-----
problems making Certificate Request
140320238503584:error:0D07A097:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long:a_mbstr.c:154:maxsize=64
dpkg: error processing ssl-cert (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ssl-cert
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: At which part of the error message did you hit the road-block?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me. I am running a single install command and I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this error, I am still getting it from the ssl-cert package. However, it seems that the PHP5 package did successfully install. I saw this error while installing other LAMP packages too. There is not much available online to help resolve it and *I have not hit this problem on the Amazon EC2*.